# In yii how to create retrive fields input and compare it with databse fields

Tags: database, yii

In yii i am creating forget password functionality. after clicking on forgetpassword button, server will provide one php paga with blank text field for entering primary email id. Now how to retrive this email id in controller's method and how to check wheather this email id exist in databse. Please help me...

Comment: This guide provides some really good information that will help you write this feature: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you get started, you would put a method similar to this in your controller and create a view with a password field on it.

```
public function actionForgotPassword(){

  if(isset($_POST['email']{
    $record=User::model()->find(array(
      'select'=>'email',
      'condition'=>'email=:email',
      'params'=>array(':email'=>$_POST['email']))
    );

    if($record===null) {
      $error = 'Email invalid';
    } else {
      $newpassword = 'newrandomgeneratedpassword';
      $record->password = md5($newpassword );
      $record->save(); //you might have some issues with the user model when the password is protected for security
      //Email new password to user
    }
  }else{
    $this->render('forgetPassword'); //show the view with the password field
  }

}
```